# JS code to change parameter 'top' on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Here](https://codepen.io/Volabos/pen/eqPRZr) is the pen I've created.

**HTML**

```
<div class = 'cc'>  
    <div class = 'bb'><div class = 'aa'> Some word </div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cc {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 90px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-family: "Calibri";
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #666666;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.0);
}

.bb {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.aa {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Now I want to create a clickable event such that when user click on class `bb`, page will check the `top` parameter of class `aa` - *if it is 50% then smoothly change that to 10% and vice versa*.

I want to use JavaScript code to achieve that. How can I do that?

Comment: *"I have created a pen as follows"* No need in most cases, you can do your runnable example **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: Do you use any frameworks or libraries?

Comment: Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: I must agree with @T.J.Crowder. Try some stuff, see what happens, and come back if you can't get it to work. SO is happy to help, but not so happy to do the work for you :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder et al - sorry I dont have any idea how to ask js to determine the current value of 'top'

Comment: Research `get (or change) css value via js` or `get (or change) css value via jquery`. These have been asked and answered before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. It is tested and it seems to work.

```
let bb = document.querySelector('.bb');
let aa = document.querySelector('.aa');

bb.addEventListener('click', function(){

  if(window.getComputedStyle(aa).getPropertyValue('top') === '50px'){
     aa.style.top = '10%';
  }else{
     aa.style.top = '50%';
  }
})
```

First, I used `querySelector` to get `.bb` and `.aa`.

Then, I added a event listener to `bb`.
Next, in the event listener I used `window.getComputedStyle()`, got the value of `top` from it and checked if it is `50px`.

Last of all, if it is, change that to `10%`, else change it to `50%`.

I did this on CodePen, you can check it [here](https://codepen.io/zixuan75/pen/bXmRLr) (notice I changed the style from gray to white because gray is hard to read inside a black box).

Answer (score 1):

hey just tried to gave shot at it , seems its working please look into this

```
let bb = document.querySelector('.bb');
let aa = document.querySelector('.aa');

bb.addEventListener('click',e => {
  let top = window.getComputedStyle(aa).getPropertyValue('top');
  if(top === '50px'){
     aa.style.top = '10%';
  }else{
    aa.style.top = '50%';
  }
})
```